# Open source UIView with browser-like tabs for iOS

Tags: ipad, uiview, uikit

Is there an open source UIView component that supports multiple, dynamic tabbed views for the iPhone (iPad) SDK? I see several apps in the iPad App Store which utilize tabs, one such example is the [Atomic Web Browser](http://atomicwebbrowser.com/) which provides a tabbed browsing experience (like Safari on the Mac or Firefox). Instead of reinventing this functionality, I'd like to reuse an existing component.

Comment: Perhaps someone can help me improve the title of this question. It seems like no one is interested in this question. Maybe they think I should just use the existing tab bar support in the iPhone SDK? That doesn't seem to be a good approach for many, dynamic tabs (that's why I provided an example of an app which uses the types of tabs I'm trying to achieve).

Comment: Maybe "Opensource UIView with browser-like tabs for iOS?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an open source (MIT license) solution at Cocoa Controls: [BHTabBar for iOS](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bhtabbar).

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look into the Three20 framework. I haven't use it but maybe it suits your needs.

Comment: I have and unfortunately it doesn't contain a browser-like tab bar component.